# Clone & run existing project from github

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I installed Visual Studio 2017.
I wanted to clone a repository and try in my local system.
Suppose i want to clone [this](https://github.com/sarn1/example-aspnet-mvc). repo (Not mine.) Is it possible in one step?
Or else do i need to write step by step actions and necessary codes to run the project?
By checking NuGut package manager to auto download packages on build time will 
 work? I am new in ASP.Net. Is there any way to run the project in local system by just cloning.

**EDIT:**- Tried to restore packages

```
PM> dotnet restore

Welcome to .NET Core!
---------------------
Learn more about .NET Core: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs

Telemetry
---------
The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous and doesn't in
clude command-line arguments. The data is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telem
etry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.

Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry

ASP.NET Core
------------
Successfully installed the ASP.NET Core HTTPS Development Certificate.
To trust the certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' (Windows and macOS only). For establishing trust on other 
platforms refer to the platform specific documentation.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
C:\Users\win7.system3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\localhost_54920\localhost_54920.sln : Solution file error MS
B4249: Unable to build website project "SAMP". The ASP.NET compiler is only available on the .NET Framework version of MS
Build.
```

Comment: using `cmd` goto the `directory` where you want to `clone` a `repository` and then run `git clone {{ git repo path }}`. Now open and run the project.

Comment: the namespaces are not found... how to solve this problem.. While trying to install through PM, there are compitable issues with >NET Framework=4

Comment: run `dotnet restore` in Package Manger Console. I am sure the issue will be resolved.

Comment: That doesnt seems working. I updated my post

Comment: git clone the project and open the .sln file.Then you could build the project.If it has missed some packages, just redownload them on PMC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll need [.NET Framework 4.6.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) installed in your machine.

**Short answer**

Having that installed, you should be able to open the project/solution with Visual Studio, build it* and run it from there.

**Long answer**

If that was a .NET Core project, without Visual Studio it would be as easy as:

```
git clone https://github.com/sarn1/example-aspnet-mvc
cd example-aspnet-mvc\ComicBookGallery
dotnet run
```

`dotnet run` will restore (`dotnet restore`) the dependencies, build (`dotnet build`) the project and run it.

However, that's not the case, so you can only:

- Restore the nuget packages using Visual Studio or `nuget.exe` cli.
- Compile it* using or `msbuild` (use [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to be able to easily access it).
- Run it... from Visual Studio, which makes the rest of the process kind of worthless.

```
    git clone https://github.com/sarn1/example-aspnet-mvc
    cd example-aspnet-mvc
    nuget.exe restore
    msbuild /t:build
```

* You may need to apply [these changes](https://github.com/sarn1/example-aspnet-mvc/pull/1/files) to make the project compile.